# Select distinct results of sum

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been trying to find some help on this but can't seem to find any.
I have data like this on my table:

| ID | ratios |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 0,004 |
| 2222 | 0,023 |
| 2222 | 0,012 |
| 3333 | 0 |
| 4444 | 0 |
| ... | ... |

For every ID I have one or more ratio values.
And my next step is to sum them all.

```
select ID, sum(ratios)
from table
group by ID;
```

Resulting in something like this:

| ID | sum(ratios) |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 |
| 2222 | 1 |
| 3333 | 0 |
| 4444 | 0 |
| ... | ... |

Here's where I hit a wall. My goal is to check if any of the sum results goes over 1 to validate my ratios.
I was trying to select distinct the sum results but can't make it work since I'm also working with the group by clause.
Can someone you help me solve this?

Comment: [tag:sql-server] is a Microsoft product, and obviously [tag:oracle-sqldeveloper] is an Oracle product. Can you please [edit] your tags or your question to make sure we know what tech you use?

Comment: HAVING sum(ratios) >1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a having statement, which is like a WHERE statement for your aggregations, you can return all of your sums that are greater than 1.

```
select ID, sum(ratios)
from table
group by ID
having sum(ratios) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Looks like I only hit a small garden fence instead of a wall. I won't forget the having statement again

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, sum(ratios)
from table
group by ID
having sum(ratios) > 1
```

Having is like a where clause for group by.